# Setting File Metadata with Applescript or Automator

Tags: macos, applescript

I know how to set file keywords (com.apple.metadata:kMDItemKeywords) using a command line process that involves creating a plist, converting to binary  and using xattr.   It works but is painful.   I'm hoping there is a better way.

Can anyone explain how to set file metadata using Apple's tools?  Or point to websites that cover this?

All pointers appreciated.

Comment: If I am correct, the kMDitemKeywords and other attributes are not stored in the file itself, but in the Spotlight database. if you want to really store in he files themselves, use the free shell command Exiftool. It can change much more that only image tags, and it is stored in the file itself which is the only way to keep attributes among mac, Windows, Linux.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what metadata you wish to set please?

Comment: Be more specific?   I said "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemKeywords".  That's exactly the file attribute I want to set.


As for Spotlight vs file system, I said I was using xattr.   Quoting from the xattr man page:
"Extended attributes are name:value pairs associated permanently with
       files and directories..."


xattr is available with OSX, newer Linux and BSD.   Thats file based, and not spotlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify the code below to fit your needs:

```
set aFile to choose file
set a to quoted form of POSIX path of aFile

do shell script "xattr -w com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags '(\"orange\\n6\",\"test\")' " & a
```

Happy keywording!